# Connecting wordpress theme with bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following as  my functions.php

```html
<?php
function portfolio_script_enqueue()
{
 wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    $dependencies = array('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstarter-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), $dependencies ); 

    $dependenciesScript = array('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',  $dependenciesScript, '3.3.6', true );

}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","portfolio_script_enqueue");
?>
```

and header.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>My portfolio</title>
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
 <?php body_class(); ?>
```

but the bootstrap styling is not picking.Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: To call the regiser_style, you must calling wp_enqueue_style

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );` will call the registered style

Accroding to wordpress codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) `wp register style()` register a CSS style file for later use with `wp_enqueue_style()`.

So, change the code as

```
function portfolio_script_enqueue()
{
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    //enqueue the style
      wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );
```